# Как в jsPlumb отловить событие перетаскивания связи?

Tags: javascript

Т.е. нужно поймать событие когда я тащу связь куда-либо. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, есть два события: `connectionDrag` и `connectionDragStop`.

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/events.html